# How can I compare two files in a batch file?

Tags: file, comparison, batch-file, if-statement

How can I compare two files in a batch file, and perform an action based on whether or not they match? I've tried something like:

```
if file1.txt NEQ file2.txt goto label
```

but it compares the actual string "file1.txt" rather than the file. I've read about the COMP command, but it doesn't seem to work if I put it in an if statement. Does anybody know how to do this? Sorry, but I rarely use batch files and have little experience in them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I believe you can use the "FC" command and then check the errorlevel. Here's some code:

```
@echo off
:main
fc c:\filename r:\filemame > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto error

:next
echo insert next CD
pause
goto main

:error
echo failed check
```

(Pulled from http://www.computing.net/answers/dos/batch-file-command/15753.html)

Comment: also I suggest checking errorlevel 2, it's sign that something gone wrong (one of files cannot be open, disk error, etc).

Comment: Could you clarify -- does errorlevel 0 mean the same, errorlevel 1 mean different? Or vice-versa?

Comment: @CraigMcQueen Taken from the [Command line reference](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html): "-1: Invalid syntax (e.g. only one file passed); 0: The files are identical.; 1: The files are different.; 2: Cannot find at least one of the files."

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the COMP program is actually fairly easy to use. See [this question](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080827151752AARwoYC) on Yahoo answers.

Note that running `comp /?` will print the help text for the program (as does specifying the `/?` argument with any native Windows command line program). This outputs the same text you see in the answer of the question linked above.

Content from the Yahoo Answer:

```
C:\>comp /? 
Compares the contents of two files or sets of files. 

COMP [data1] [data2] [/D] [/A] [/L] [/N=number] [/C] [/OFF[LINE]] 

data1 Specifies location and name(s) of first file(s) to compare. 
data2 Specifies location and name(s) of second files to compare. 
/D Displays differences in decimal format. 
/A Displays differences in ASCII characters. 
/L Displays line numbers for differences. 
/N=number Compares only the first specified number of lines in each file. 
/C Disregards case of ASCII letters when comparing files. 
/OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set. 

To compare sets of files, use wildcards in data1 and data2 parameters.
```

Comment: gazers of that answer, note that `comp` has problem: after each comparison, it interactively asks user if he wants to compare more files. And there is no switch to turn off that query, so best option is to `echo N|comp file1 file2`. Otherwise, comp is faster because it compares sizes first, and stops comparison after displaying 10 differences, and can compare groups of files using masks. On other hand, `FC` compares full files despite size, displays all differences, and tries to resync for similarities on different offsets (as unix diff).

Comment: @LogicDaemon There is a switch to stop prompting for more files  

`/M         Do not prompt for compare more files.`

Comment: @tiboo it only appeared in some recent Windows 10 version, I guess in 2019 at least.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below example to build reports based on file differences:

```
set %Batch_Work_Space_Dir%=folder for your batch file and temp resource files
set file_1=name of file
set file_2=name of file

fc %file_1% %file_1%t > %Batch_Work_Space_Dir%\Are_They_Different.txt

powershell -command "(Get-Content %Batch_Work_Space_Dir%\Are_They_Different.txt) | select -skip 1 | Set-Content %Batch_Work_Space_Dir%\Are_They_Different.txt"
set /p Diff_Found=<%Batch_Work_Space_Dir%\Are_They_Different.txt
if %Diff_Found:~0,17%" == "FC: no difference" (
  execute commands
 )
```