# Windows batch script: Perform a command if two files are the same!

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, compare

I would have thought this was going to be a very simple task but I have been struggling with it for a couple of days now, and slightly frustrated! I am not very familiar with Windows batch scripts so please if you know the answer, keep it as simple as possible :)

Basically, I have a Windows Shutdown script (.bat file) in which I would like to know if two text files are the same (i.e. their content is exactly the same), and if so, perform a goto command (e.g. goto line10)

I can't figure out how to do this! Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671642/how-can-i-compare-two-files-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This script should work:

```
fc /b file1 file2 > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto files_differ
[files are the same, do something here]

:files_differ
[files are not the same, do something here]
```

Answer (score 20):

Without the goto:

```
fc /b file1 file2 > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo different
) else (
    echo same
)
```

Comment: Note that `if errorlevel 1` [actually means that errorlevel is 1 or more](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743). `FC` sets errorlevel 2 if one of the files doesn't exist. So the first case really is `echo different, or at least one doesn't exist`.